# Ajax Call In Each Loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I create dynamic html buttons 
I want for each button, when i press one of them, then create a ajax call to take value. But my problem is, that I get as many consoles as their number of buttons..

**My php code is:**

```
if(isset($_POST['disable_appointment'])) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM appointments";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $return_arr = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $appointment_date = $row['appointment_date'];
        $appointment_time = $row['appointment_time'];

        $return_arr[] = array("appointment_time"=> $appointment_time);
    }

    exit(json_encode($return_arr));

}
```

**My JQuery code is:**

```
$( ".appointment_button" ).each(function(index) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'../../groomer/groomer_server.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{
            disable_appointment:1
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing... but my first guess is that instead of `.each` you actually want `.click` or `.on('click',`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what your code means : `$(button).each( ajax )` means : for each button, make an ajax call

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what your question is, but my best guess is that you want to use [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) or `.on('click',` instead of the `.each`...

```
$( ".appointment_button" ).click(function(index) {
   // Do something when the individual button is clicked...
   $.ajax({
     ...
   });
});
```

At the moment, your code will just run the `.ajax` against all the found elements